# Group by an attribute and count the records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need to group the results of a query by their name and display the amount of results for each name.

controller:

```
def show
@task = Task.where(:name => params[:name])
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @task }
   end
end
```

I need to define something that outputs something like this:

*show.html.erb*:

```
Name | # of Tasks

Alan |   2
Bob  |   1
```

How can I accomplish that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`group_by` method](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by):

```
@tasks.group_by(&:name)

# this will output:
{
  'Ben' => [<Task id:(...)>],
  'Alon' => [<Task id:(...)>, <Task id:(...)>, ...],
  #...
}
```

In your view, you could use it like this:

```
<% @tasks.group_by(&:name).each do |name, tasks| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= name %></td>
    <td><%= tasks.size %></td> # the tasks variable is an Array of Tasks
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

### Better way

You can also do it in only one SQL request:

```
Task.count(:group => 'name')
# should return a Hash like:
{
  'Ben': 2,
  'Alon': 5,
  # ...
}
```

How to use it in your view?

```
<% @tasks_count.each do |task_name, task_count| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task_name %></td>
    <td><%= task_count %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

MrYoushiji gave the correct answer. 
But you can fetch information you need by single sql request:

```
@task_counts = Task.group(:name).count

# this will output:
{
  'Ben' => 1,
  'Alon' => 2,
  #...
}
```

Usage:

```
<% @task_counts.each do |name, count| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= name %></td>
    <td><%= count %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This will raise an error in many kind of DB systems: (PostGres for example: `PG::Error: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I test that with mysql because the question have mysql tag. And it generates right sql: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, name AS name FROM `tasks` GROUP BY name